# Cannot read property forms of undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, components, onload

i have a form in react, not a redux form and i want the form to be auto submitted. Here is my code:

```
class DummyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onLoadEvent = this.onLoadEvent.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.onLoadEvent();
  }

  onLoadEvent() {
    this.document.forms.threedfrom.submit();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <body>
      <form
        name="threedfrom"
        action={this.props.acsUrl}
        method="POST"
      >
          <textarea
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            name="PaReq"
            value={this.props.pareqMessage}
          />
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="MD"
          value={this.props.reservationCode}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

But when the component is mounted i got the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forms' of undefined means that document is undefined. How is this possible and what i'm missing? Thanks a lot

Comment: where should `this.document` be defined?

Comment: I think by `this.document` you mean simply `document`

Comment: i want to take the part of the dom with formname threedfrom. Is the way i implement this wrong?

Comment: or should I implement this with another way;

Comment: Why not just call the function that is called when submitted directly? Simulating submit events is primarily for writing test cases only.

Comment: Because i want to submit the form when e component is mounted

Answer (score 0):

this.document means document is a member of this class. You can use ref to do a submit as you did